# PHP GMP: convert string to number ( change base )

Tags: php, gmp

In GMP extension in PHP it is possible to convert a large number to string. For example:

`gmp_strval("1234999999999999999999999999999999213123123999999", 36);`

gives:

`p9owzsy9oqh5k9wdw0ve3si9futy5fj`

Question: how to perform inverse transformation - make 
`1234999999999999999999999999999999213123123999999`
out of 
`p9owzsy9oqh5k9wdw0ve3si9futy5fj`
?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `gmp_init()` function takes an optional `base` argument.

```
gmp_init('p9owzsy9oqh5k9wdw0ve3si9futy5fj', 36)
```